# Geo::IP module does not return all country codes

Tags: perl

I'm trying to read a file containing IP addresses and then pass them to `Geo::IP` to look up their country code, but my code only returns the country code for the last IP in the file.

```
open(my $in, "<", "ips.txt") or die "can't open the file $!";
my @lines = <$in>;

use Geo::IP;
my $gi = Geo::IP->new(GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
foreach (@lines) {
    print $gi->country_code_by_addr($_);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

[chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input:

```
open(my $in, "<", "ips.txt") or die "can't open the file $!";
my @lines = <$in>;
chomp @lines;
```

Comment: Thanks toolic, I eventually came to the same answer, a chomp of the input was needed.